# Find a and b if it is possible

Tags: functions, derivatives

$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{e^{ax+b}-1}{x}, & x>0 \\
      \frac{x}{2}+1, & x\leq 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right. $

If possible, find the values $a$ and $b$ that make $f(x)$ differentiable.

So the first thing I do is check for continuity. So I plug in for $x=0$ and get

$\frac{e^{b}-1}{0}=1$
But I can't have $0$ in the denominator. So does that make the function discontinuous and therefor not differentiable? Or should I rather be thinking that when $f(x)$ gets close to $x=0$ from the right side, $f(x)$ will approach negative infinity, but from the left side it will approach $1$?

Comment: Plug in for $x=0$ in the part defined for $0.$ For the part you wrongly used, only the limit in $0$ has to be computed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see that now! But even if the function is not differentiable in x=0, can I still find out what a and b are?

Comment: You can show that b=0 by noticing that $\frac{e^{ax+b}-1}{x}$ goes to $\pm\infty$ at $x=0$ and such the function would not be differentiable at $x=0$ when $b=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definition of differentiability that we can use is that a function $f$ is differentiable at $x=t$ if $$\lim\limits_{x\to t^-}\frac{f(x)-f(t)}{x-t}=\lim\limits_{x\to t^+}\frac{f(x)-f(t)}{x-t}.$$

In this particular case, we have $t=0$.  Evaluating the $t^+$ limit first, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\frac{x}2+1)-(\frac02+1)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x}2}{x}\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}

So really, this problem is a limit problem disguised as a differentiability problem.  The problem we want to solve:

> Suppose $g(x)=\frac{e^{ax+b}-1}{x}$.  Find $a$ and $b$ such that $g'(0)=\frac12$.

Can you take it from here?

---

Edit:  using the known limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$
we know that the function $f$ is continuous if $a=1$ and $b=0$.  Therefore, we have $$g(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$ and we want to know if the slope of $g(x)$ approaches $\frac12$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from the left.  [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0%5E-+d%2Fdx+%28e%5Ex-1%29%2Fx+) suggests that it does.  Can you figure out how to prove it?

Edit2:  [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ixo7ewkmg1) is a graph on Desmos that shows the function $f(x)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to be honest. So I evaluated the limit from the left side, and I got $e^{b}-1$. I then set this equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. I then find b that is ln(3/2). Is this right? And if this is true, how should I evalute $a$? And one more question, if the function is discontinuous in x=0. Then it can not be differentiable in x=0?

Comment: You have to approach the same value from both sides, and you have to approach the same slope from both sides.

Comment: But the function won't approach the same value from left and right when plugging in x=0. I'm sorry, for all the questions by the way. I just really want to understand this.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer.

Comment: I took some time, but I finally found the answer now. Thank you so much @Andrew Chin